# How to show the only the upcoming 3 months in date pickers

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<input id="datepicker" type="text">
```

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  minDate: 0,
  beforeShowDay: function(d) {
    var day = d.getDate();
    return [day == 5 || day == 10 || day == 15 || day == 20 || day == 25];
  },
  beforeShow: function() {
    var dateTime = new Date();
    var hour = dateTime.getHours();
    var minute = dateTime.getMinutes();
    if (hour >= 18 && minute > 30) {
      $(this).datepicker("option", "minDate", "1");
    }
  }
});
```

How to show the only the upcoming 3 months from current i.e feb, march and april in date pickers and enable 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 dates in every and disable the date after 6:30 PM

Comment: End date : https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#enddate

Comment: $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ maxDate: "+2M" }); this will allow you to add only two months from now

Comment: Disable certain dates : https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#datesdisabled

Comment: and if your requirement is only that  dates why do you use a date picker ?? I suggest you use <select> instead of a date picker

Answer (score 0):

you can disable all other date except upcoming three months.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  maxDate: '+3M', 
  numberOfMonths:3,
  minDate: 0,
  beforeShowDay: function(d) {
    var day = d.getDate();
    return [day == 5 || day == 10 || day == 15 || day == 20 || day == 25];
  },
  beforeShow: function() {
    var dateTime = new Date();
    var hour = dateTime.getHours();
    var minute = dateTime.getMinutes();
    if (hour >= 18 && minute > 30) {
      $(this).datepicker("option", "minDate", "1");
    }
  }
});
```